# Nginx wp-admin Upstreamtime

Tags: nginx, wordpress

I've setup Nginx as per instructions, everything works, but my wp-admin is returning a 504 error (`upstream timeout`).

Everything works correctly, all rewrites etc.

I've tried scaling it right back to basics with no caching etc... but still nothing.

```
fastcgi_cache_path /var/run/nginx-cache levels=1:2 keys_zone=MYAPP:100m inactive=60m;
fastcgi_cache_key "$scheme$request_method$host$request_uri";

server {
    listen 82 default_server;
    listen [::]:82 default_server ipv6only=on;

    root /mnt/wpmount/nen;
    index index.php index.html index.htm;

    # Make site accessible from http://localhost/
    server_name localhost;

    location / {

        if ($args ~* "^s=(.*)$")
        {
            return 301 /search/$1;
        }
        #try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php?q=$uri&$args;
        try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php?$args;
    }

        location ~* \.(?:jpg|jpeg|gif|png|ico|cur|gz|svg|svgz|mp4|ogg|ogv|webm|htc)$ {
          expires 1M;
          access_log off;
          add_header Cache-Control "public";
        }

    location ~* /(?:uploads|files)/.*\.php$ {
            deny all;
    }

    location ~* \.(pl|cgi|py|sh|lua)\$ {
            return 444;
    }

    # pass the PHP scripts to FastCGI server listening on 127.0.0.1:9000
    #
    location ~ \.php$ {
        try_files $uri =404;
        fastcgi_split_path_info ^(.+\.php)(/.+)$;
        fastcgi_pass unix:/var/run/php5-fpm.sock;
        fastcgi_index index.php;
        fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
        include fastcgi_params;

        fastcgi_cache MYAPP;
        fastcgi_cache_valid 200 60m;

        fastcgi_cache_bypass $no_cache;
        fastcgi_no_cache $no_cache;
        add_header X-Cache $upstream_cache_status;
    }

    location ~ /\.ht {
        deny all;
    }

#Cache everything by default
set $no_cache 0;

#Don't cache POST requests
if ($request_method = POST)
{
    set $no_cache 1;
}

#Don't cache if the URL contains a query string
if ($query_string != "")
{
    set $no_cache 1;
}

#Don't cache if there is a cookie called PHPSESSID
    if ($http_cookie = "PHPSESSID")
    {
        set $no_cache 1;
    }
}
```

Comment: Are you using a cache in front of nginx? That's a really strange Nginx configuration for Wordpress, I don't even see where you call PHP. You need to give more information about your environment, what works, and what doesn't more clearly.

Comment: Sorry - turns out only half of my config posted. I use the NGINX cache to cache the rendered PHP output. PHP processed over socket via php5-fpm. The site and re-writes work, but wp-admin just returns 504.

Comment: Nothing stands out as obviously incorrect. Have a look at my published configurations, which you can download half way down the page on this link https://www.photographerstechsupport.com/tutorials/hosting-wordpress-on-aws-tutorial-pt1-introduction-configuration-downloads/

Comment: I'd turn caching off while I work this out. Add headers to make sure the request for wp_admin/index.php is definitely going through the right location block. You have a bunch more stuff in your PHP location than I have, though most is similar.

Comment: Good idea re the header, ill report back.